# How to resolve multiple GET requests in a forEach using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise, node-request

I have a number of stock tickers in a JSON file that I want to use to send multiple GET requests to get the price of that stock. The problem I'm having is how to send them off in parallel and how to resolve them.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
const stocks = require('./stocks.json')
var request = require("request");

    var stockTickers = stocks.map(x => x.stockopediaTicker)
    stockTickers.forEach(ticker => {
        var promises = []
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.stockopedia.com/ajax/get_prices/' + ticker + '/'
        };
        let todaysQuote = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                rej(error)
                res(body)
            });
        })
        promises.push(todaysQuote)
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then((results) => {
            console.log(results)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: `var promises = []` is defined in a scope that `Promise.all` doesn't have access to. Try defining `promises` outside the `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path with your code.

1. You just need to only call `rej(err)` if there is actually an error
2. You shouldn't be attempting to share the same options object with all your requests (that might or might not cause problems)
3. You need to declare `promises` in a higher scope where it can be used with `Promise.all(promises)`:

Here's what it would look like after fixing up those issues:

```
const stocks = require('./stocks.json')
const request = require("request");

let promises = [];
let stockTickers = stocks.map(x => x.stockopediaTicker);

stockTickers.forEach(ticker => {
    let todaysQuote = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.stockopedia.com/ajax/get_prices/' + ticker + '/'
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                rej(error);
            } else {
                res(body);
            }
        });
    })
    promises.push(todaysQuote)
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

---

The request-promise module is simpler to use as it already includes a promise wrapper and it's probably easier to use `.map()` to accumulate your array of promises.

```
const stocks = require('./stocks.json')
const rp = require("request-promise");

Promise.all(stocks.map(x => {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.stockopedia.com/ajax/get_prices/' + x.stockopediaTicker + '/'
    };
    return rp(options);
})).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is an error and only `rej` if there is an error:

```
let todaysQuote = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
                return rej(error)
            }

            res(body)
        });
    })
```

Right now, you're "rejecting" every response.

Comment: I was under the impression that a promise was only rejected if `request` raised an error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "request" but using "request-promise-native" you can simplify some things like this.

```
const stocks = require('./stocks.json');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const parseStocks = (stocks)=>Promise.all(stocks.map(requestQuote));

const requestQuote = ({stockopediaTicker})=>{
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://www.stockopedia.com/ajax/get_prices/${stockopediaTicker}/`
    };
    return request(options)
}

parseStocks(stocks).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Normally I refrain from suggesting dependency changes in an answer, but in this case, 'request-promise-native' is suggested by the 'request' docs. If you plan on using promises you may want to switch. It's usually best practice to avoid combining callbacks and promise chains together.